# Correcting JSON result object

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a controller action like this:

```
List<string> abcd = new List<string>()
foreach (var i in images)
{
    abcd.Add("{url:'"+GetImageUrl(i)+"'}");
}     
return Json(abcd, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

So the output of `abcd` is

```
["{url:'/PropertyImage/GetPropertyImage?imageId=1'}", "{url:'/PropertyImage/GetPropertyImage?imageId=2'}", "{url:'/PropertyImage/GetPropertyImage?imageId=8'}"]
```

But the result I want is:

```
images:[{url:'/PropertyImage/GetPropertyImage?imageId=1'}, {url:'/PropertyImage/GetPropertyImage?imageId=2'}, {url:'/PropertyImage/GetPropertyImage?imageId=8'}]
```

In my JavaScript, I have

```
$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: url,
     success: function (result) {
         console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
         var data = {
             images: [result]
         };

         template = "{{#images}}<a href='{{url}}'><img class='imageborder' src='{{url}}' style='width:150px;height:150px'></img></a>{{/images}}";
         renderedOutput= Mustache.to_html(template,data);
         $('#Propertyimagelinks').html(renderedOutput);
     }
 });
```

How can I get the correct output?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to manually manipulate JSON strings, it seems a lot simpler to use ASP.NET MVC's built in JSON serialization functionality and a little bit of Linq, like this:

```
var abcd = images.Select(i => new { url = GetImageUrl(i) }).ToList();
return Json(abcd, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

And in your JavaScript result handler, use this:

```
var data = { images: result };
```

---

Alternatively you can use this in your controller:

```
var abcd = images.Select(i => new { url = GetImageUrl(i) }).ToList();
return Json(new { images = abcd }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

And in your JavaScript:

```
var data = result;
```